# Heroku deploy graphql blank page

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, graphql, dyno

I am trying to deploy api graphql located in here
 => https://github.com/DimiMikadze/create-social-network 
but I'm facing some issues and a page is still blank. (frontend was deployed at netlify)
It works in dev mode.
**I wonder if paid account can solve that problem. I'm not sure is it because of my free heroku account and dyno limit or heroku issue or a broken on production deployment**

It works here => https://worldexplorer.netlify.app/
Config vars has been added without PORT, should I also add PORT if it's dynamic on heroku?
My sec guess is a replace function ws, http to ws, https.
I've checked everything and it's still fail.
I've added useUnifiedTopology to mongoose.connect() still not working.
Any suggestions ?

**err H12, Stopping all processes with SIGTERM ,Process exited with status 143, dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503**

**Full review of heroku logs -t**

```
2020-06-12T10:44:56.446529+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-06-12T10:44:59.369642+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020-06-12T10:45:01.534501+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
2020-06-12T10:45:01.535655+00:00 app[web.1]: server ready at http://localhost:3044/graphql
2020-06-12T10:45:01.535782+00:00 app[web.1]: Subscriptions ready at ws://localhost:3044/graphql
2020-06-12T10:45:01.586325+00:00 app[web.1]: DB connected
2020-06-12T10:45:03.055672+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-06-12T10:45:03.169058+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-06-12T10:45:06.816310+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
2020-06-12T10:45:06.817765+00:00 app[web.1]: server ready at http://localhost:3844/graphql
2020-06-12T10:45:06.817908+00:00 app[web.1]: Subscriptions ready at ws://localhost:3844/graphql
2020-06-12T10:45:06.883664+00:00 app[web.1]: DB connected
2020-06-12T10:45:07.327247+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-06-12T10:45:12.038980+00:00 app[api]: Set MAIL_USER config vars by user cichy96@gmail.com
2020-06-12T10:45:12.038980+00:00 app[api]: Release v11 created by user cichy96@gmail.com
2020-06-12T10:45:13.562118+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-06-12T10:45:13.575923+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-06-12T10:45:14.564507+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-06-12T10:45:14.646488+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-06-12T10:45:17.663370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020-06-12T10:45:24.976462+00:00 app[api]: Release v12 created by user cichy96@gmail.com
2020-06-12T10:45:24.976462+00:00 app[api]: Set MAIL_PASS config vars by user cichy96@gmail.com
2020-06-12T10:45:25.614269+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
2020-06-12T10:45:25.614985+00:00 app[web.1]: server ready at http://localhost:59382/graphql
2020-06-12T10:45:25.615090+00:00 app[web.1]: Subscriptions ready at ws://localhost:59382/graphql
2020-06-12T10:45:25.667679+00:00 app[web.1]: DB connected
2020-06-12T10:45:25.697175+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-06-12T10:45:26.107722+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-06-12T10:45:26.119837+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-06-12T10:45:27.911856+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-06-12T10:45:27.998867+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-06-12T10:45:29.575354+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020-06-12T10:45:36.721995+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
2020-06-12T10:45:36.731164+00:00 app[web.1]: server ready at http://localhost:57681/graphql
2020-06-12T10:45:36.731169+00:00 app[web.1]: Subscriptions ready at ws://localhost:57681/graphql
2020-06-12T10:45:36.782607+00:00 app[web.1]: DB connected
2020-06-12T10:45:37.182011+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-06-12T10:50:16.497620+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=qualityprotector.herokuapp.com request_id=043d81b7-80fe-46bb-a5e4-53860f1bc38d fwd="83.22.243.180" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=14ms status=404 bytes=505 protocol=https
2020-06-12T10:50:22.382324+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided
2020-06-12T10:50:22.382358+00:00 app[web.1]: at Proxy.module.exports (/app/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:53:17)
2020-06-12T10:50:22.382359+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/utils/apollo-server.js:17:32
2020-06-12T10:50:22.382360+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2020-06-12T10:50:22.382361+00:00 app[web.1]: at checkAuthorization (/app/utils/apollo-server.js:16:10)
2020-06-12T10:50:22.382361+00:00 app[web.1]: at ApolloServer.context (/app/utils/apollo-server.js:45:28)
2020-06-12T10:50:22.382362+00:00 app[web.1]: at ApolloServer.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/ApolloServer.js:467:38)
2020-06-12T10:50:22.382362+00:00 app[web.1]: at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
2020-06-12T10:50:22.382363+00:00 app[web.1]: at fulfilled (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/ApolloServer.js:5:58)
2020-06-12T10:50:22.382363+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2020-06-12T10:50:22.382956+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
2020-06-12T10:50:22.384392+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
2020-06-12T10:50:52.373293+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/graphql" host=qualityprotector.herokuapp.com request_id=c83cff9c-21ec-4a3f-a0e8-c4379571a39e fwd="83.22.243.180" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-06-12T10:50:52.734000+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=qualityprotector.herokuapp.com request_id=2106dcdb-db6c-4319-89d1-849c5d3c6dd4 fwd="83.22.243.180" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=516 protocol=https
2020-06-12T10:58:47.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user cichy96@gmail.com
2020-06-12T10:59:33.211085+00:00 app[api]: Release v13 created by user cichy96@gmail.com
2020-06-12T10:59:33.211085+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 1fccd247 by user cichy96@gmail.com
2020-06-12T10:59:34.584781+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-06-12T10:59:34.598736+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-06-12T10:59:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-06-12T10:59:35.928901+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-06-12T10:59:36.040285+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-06-12T10:59:37.657728+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020-06-12T10:59:45.461692+00:00 app[web.1]: server ready at http://localhost:26575/graphql
2020-06-12T10:59:45.462171+00:00 app[web.1]: Subscriptions ready at ws://localhost:26575/graphql
2020-06-12T10:59:45.521392+00:00 app[web.1]: DB connected
2020-06-12T10:59:45.619943+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-06-12T11:00:47.664793+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-06-12T11:00:47.680114+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-06-12T11:00:49.169628+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-06-12T11:00:49.286154+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-06-12T11:00:50.587728+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020-06-12T11:00:56.856897+00:00 app[web.1]: server ready at http://localhost:51664/graphql
2020-06-12T11:00:56.859410+00:00 app[web.1]: Subscriptions ready at ws://localhost:51664/graphql
2020-06-12T11:00:56.907031+00:00 app[web.1]: DB connected
2020-06-12T11:00:57.279110+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-06-12T11:01:34.264690+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2020-06-12T11:01:34.278533+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-06-12T11:01:35.229897+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-06-12T11:01:35.322805+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-06-12T11:01:37.425699+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2020-06-12T11:01:46.205694+00:00 app[web.1]: server ready at http://localhost:21876/graphql
2020-06-12T11:01:46.206253+00:00 app[web.1]: Subscriptions ready at ws://localhost:21876/graphql
2020-06-12T11:01:46.320655+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-06-12T11:01:46.357976+00:00 app[web.1]: DB connected
2020-06-12T11:10:41.526938+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided
2020-06-12T11:10:41.526946+00:00 app[web.1]: at Proxy.module.exports (/app/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:53:17)
2020-06-12T11:10:41.526947+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/utils/apollo-server.js:17:32
2020-06-12T11:10:41.526948+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2020-06-12T11:10:41.526948+00:00 app[web.1]: at checkAuthorization (/app/utils/apollo-server.js:16:10)
2020-06-12T11:10:41.526949+00:00 app[web.1]: at ApolloServer.context (/app/utils/apollo-server.js:45:28)
2020-06-12T11:10:41.526949+00:00 app[web.1]: at ApolloServer.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/ApolloServer.js:467:38)
2020-06-12T11:10:41.526950+00:00 app[web.1]: at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
2020-06-12T11:10:41.526950+00:00 app[web.1]: at fulfilled (/app/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/ApolloServer.js:5:58)
2020-06-12T11:10:41.526950+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2020-06-12T11:10:41.527095+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
2020-06-12T11:10:41.527237+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
2020-06-12T11:11:11.489296+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/graphql" host=qualityprotector.herokuapp.com request_id=e18fbbb6-1b40-4cd7-a9c1-d0a9acef05f5 fwd="83.22.243.180" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-06-12T11:35:59.484532+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2020-06-12T11:35:59.486103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2020-06-12T11:36:00.878335+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-06-12T11:36:01.035761+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143

CHROME CONSOLE OUTPUT - am assuming that Error is caused by heroku free account with dyno limit thats why WS lost connection.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at Module.93 (index.js:22)
    at f ((index):1)
    at Object.66 (background.jpg:1)
    at f ((index):1)
    at a ((index):1)
    at Array.e [as push] ((index):1)
    at main.43d14637.chunk.js:1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have deployed only the graphql server you can't make `GET` request on `/` because there is no routing, also `GET` on `/graphql` is disabled.

> When `NODE_ENV` is set to `production`, GraphQL Playground (as well as introspection) is disabled as a production best-practice.

But by default on heroku `NODE_ENV` is set to production. To test you graphql server with the GraphQL IDE set it to `development` or [enable playground in production](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/testing/graphql-playground/#enabling-graphql-playground-in-production).

You can also use an API client like postman to make only POST request on `/graphql` without changing your configuration.

Comment: a frontend serves at netlify Will try with introspection set as true. Thanks for your effort.